# Google Checkout Parse Private-merchant-Data C#

Tags: c#, google-checkout

I am trying to figure out how to parse the private-merchant-data variable sent back by google checkout.  I've tried the following but I get an error when google posts back to my page:

privatedata = ThisItem.merchantprivateitemdata.Any[0].Value.ToString();

I only have one child node returned by google and that is

`<`MERCHANT_DATA_HIDDEN`>`ae36ca4d-af36-4f69-8075-34441ff5130b`<`/MERCHANT_DATA_HIDDEN`>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code that parses the Merchant Private Data:

```
GCheckout.AutoGen.anyMultiple oneAnyMultiple =
  inputNewOrderNotification.shoppingcart.merchantprivatedata;
System.Xml.XmlNode[] oneXmlNodeArray = oneAnyMultiple.Any;
string hiddenMerchantPrivateData = oneXmlNodeArray[0].InnerText;
```

I'm starting from the ShoppingCart item on the NewOrderNotification object.  It appears that you may be starting elsewhere so adjust accordingly as needed.